# Laravel findOrFail method for multiple table

Tags: php, laravel

There is two tables categories and category types. I'm trying get category by slug and category type with id. How can I check whether these two tables and data exists ?

My code:

```
public function typeIndex($slug, $typeId)
    {
        $category = Category::findBySlug($slug)->with('types')->whereHas('types',function(Builder $builder) use ($typeId){
            return $builder->where('id',$typeId);
        });

        return view('frontend.category.index', compact('category'));
    }
```

Comment: what's wrong now ? now you can check `$category` to see if it exists

Comment: Where exactly are you `findOrFail()`ing?

Comment: @MahdiYounesi ı try to get ModelNotFoundException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$category = Category::whereHas('types' , function($query) use($typeId){
    $query->where('id' , $typeId);
})->where('slug' , $slug)->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: Try this answer